# Configuring reverse DNS on BIND 9.7.3

Tags: bind, debian-squeeze, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I'm seeing the following in /var/log/mail.log

UPDATE :I own the mentioned public IP addresses.

```
The IP address sending this message does not have a PTR 550-5.7.1 record
setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from IPs 550-5.7.1 with missing PTR records.
```

I need to **setup reverse DNS by configuring PTR records** on my DNS server and I'm having a hard time figuring what I'm doing wrong.

So far I have added in /etc/bind/zones/example.com.db

```
$TTL 86400; 1 day
@               IN SOA  a.ns.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                                2016090901 ; serial
                                60         ; refresh (1 minute)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                3600000    ; expire (5 weeks 6 days 16 hours)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )

1.196.198.in-addr.arpa. IN NS a.ns.example.com
1.196.198.in-addr.arpa. IN NS b.ns.example.com

11              IN      PTR mail.example.com
6               IN      NS      a.ns.example.com.
9               IN      NS      b.ns.example.com.
                        MX      5 mail.example.com.
mail                    A       198.196.1.11
mx                      A       198.196.1.11
smtp                    A       198.196.1.11
www        60     IN    A       198.196.1.22
example.com. 60   IN    A       198.196.1.22
```

and in /etc/bind/named.conf

```
  GNU nano 2.2.4                                                       File: named.conf                                                                                                                      

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035

        listen-on { 198.196.1.6; };
        listen-on-v6 { "none"; };

        recursion no;

        allow-transfer { 198.196.1.9; };
        also-notify { 198.196.1.9; };
};

controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; };
};

zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/example2.com.db";
};

zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/example.com.db";
};

zone "1.196.198.in-addr.arpa" IN {
type master;
file "1.196.198.in-addr.arpa";
allow-update { none; };
};
```

and still when I do a PTR lookup I'm getting

```
dns2.xxxx.xy  x.x.x.x  AUTH  140 ms  Received 1 Referrals , rcode=NAME_ERROR    1.196.198.in-addr.arpa. 14400 IN SOA mname=dns1.xxxx.xy rname=hostmaster.xxxx.xy serial=xxxxxx,
```

Comment: You can't put a PTR record in your forward DNS zone. Change the "file" argument to reference an actual file, and create there your reverse DNS zone for 1.196.198.in-addr.arpa. That is where your PTR record belongs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no delegation of neither 1.196.198.in-addr.arpa nor 196.198.in-addr.arpa zone on the DNS servers authoritative for 198.in-addr.arpa zone.

This is either your task to properly set it up or whoever sold/rented you the address space. Sole PTR record on your nameserver is not enough, the whole delegation chain must be also in place for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, your ISP or your hosting provider gives this information out when their DNS servers get queried for your reverse DNS entries.
  Connect to your ISP or owner of the IP address 198.196.1.11 and he will resolve the problem with PTR records.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it. I own the  IP addresses.

Comment: Then @Andy is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If by owning you mean that you've purchased IP, delegation entity is still company that sold or rented that IP to you. Using IP is one thing, controlling reverse lookup zone is another.

These steps imply that you are owner of this IP.

1. https://stat.ripe.net/ and do a lookup for this IP
2. Check DNS tab to see NS's that are delegated for reverse lookups for this IP
3. If you have access to those NS's, setup reverse dns zone for that IP, Andy mentioned how